# Batch: How to echo a set /p with special characters into a file?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, special-characters

I'm working on a script where I have the following code:

```
:top  
Echo Enter Message
set /p msg=">"
if "%msg%"=="C" goto cancel
echo %msg% >> File.txt
goto top
:cancel
```

I'm looking for a way for the set /p to accept `&^*<>?|` and all that stuff and still echo it into the File. Is this possible? Currently the script just crahses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: Delayed Expansion

One way to do what you want is to use [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) which leaves special characters alone.

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion command.

```
:top  
Echo Enter Message
set /p msg=">"
if "%msg%"=="C" goto cancel
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !msg! >> File.txt
endlocal
goto top
:cancel
```

As you can see, you will need to use `!msg!` instead of `%msg%`.

## Method 2: Quotes

Putting quotes around the variable also leaves special characters alone, with the side-effect of having those quotes pass into your output as well.

```
:top  
Echo Enter Message
set /p msg=">"
if "%msg%"=="C" goto cancel
echo "%msg%" >> File.txt
goto top
:cancel
```